# mail server: retry timeout issues to and from specific domain

Tags: email, smtp

we have a dv server with mediatmeple, running apache 2.2, and plesk panel 10.3.

for some reason, when sending mail from our domain to theirs, or when they send email to ours, the messages bounce back with the '`retry timeout`' error.

before messages bounce back which we send out to this domain, i see them stuck in the mail queue in plesk panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWobo.png

example of info in bounced message:

```
> > Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
> > 
> > 
> >> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
> >>
> >> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
> >> recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
> >>
> >> mike@floridaseating.com
> >> retry timeout exceeded
> >> errol@floridaseating.com
> >> retry timeout exceeded
> >>
> >> ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
> >>
> >> Return-path: <claudio@sitconf.com>
> >> Received: from cpe00265acde45a-cm000e5c6e3f4e.cpe.net.cable.rogers.com 
> >> ([174.112.173.113] helo=sales)
> >> by host.interavenuehosting.com with smtp (Exim 4.69)
> >> (envelope-from <claudio@sitconf.com>)
> >> id 1S7Uvm-0008KS-3q; Tue, 13 Mar 2012 12:50:38 -0400
> >> Message-ID: <872EF71E95BA453EA0F8870024C3A22A@sales>
> >> From: "Claudio D'Ulisse" <claudio@sitconf.com>
> >> To: "Errol Rosario" <errol@floridaseating.com>,
> >> "MIKE BERG" <mike@floridaseating.com>
> >> Subject: test
> >> Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2012 12:50:31 -0400
> >> MIME-Version: 1.0
> >> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
> >> boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00E0_01CD0117.DFCD9440"
> >> X-Priority: 3
> >> X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
> >> Importance: Normal
> >> X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 14.0.8117.416
> >> X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V14.0.8117.416
> >>
> >> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
> >>
> >> ------=_NextPart_000_00E0_01CD0117.DFCD9440
> >> Content-Type: text/plain;
> >> charset="iso-8859-1"
> >> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
> >>
> >> can you confirm you get this email please?
```

the maillog (`/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog`) [see log](http://tinypaste.com/39ba92a5)

a quick dns report - anything vital on there in need of attention? http://www.dnssniffer.com/en/report/advanced/floridaseating.com

SOLVED- response from Media Temple support:

> Checking the domain names for an MX lookup, the IP address that was
>   returned was on our blacklist due to malicious activity. As there has
>   not been any recent malicious activity from this IP address, we were
>   able to remove the ban. You should be able to receive email from
>   sitconf.com / suite22.ca now. Please verify.
>
> If you have any further questions regarding your (mt) Media Temple
>   services, please feel free to contact us at any time.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Customer Support (mt) Media Temple  877-578-4000  310-564-2007
>   (mt) Current System Status: http://status.mediatemple.net (mt) User
>   Forums: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/824/ Follow us on Twitter!
>   http://twitter.com/mediatemple

Comment: Hire **good** postmaster?

Comment: @Lazy Badger a thought.

Comment: And hostmaser also

Comment: Can you post errors from the server logs as well? This error is non-verbose and pretty useless.

Comment: @goblinbox just updated the question with a link to a paste of the maillog

Comment: @Lazy Badger ..and a host of other things! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from fixing IN PTR records for MX-hosts (they are domain-emitters also, yes?!)

**Shit 1 - mail.floridaseating.com**

```
Quering 8.8.8.8 for {158.99.70.216.in-addr.arpa.,ANY}
Received answer from 8.8.8.8
  Not authoritative

Answers for 158.99.70.216.in-addr.arpa.:
  -> [PTR] floridaseating.com.
```

**Shit 2 - sitconf.com**

```
Quering 8.8.8.8 for {150.161.223.206.in-addr.arpa.,ANY}
Received answer from 8.8.8.8
  Not authoritative

Answers for 150.161.223.206.in-addr.arpa.:
  -> [PTR] 206-223-161-150.beanfield.net.
```

But now

```
Mar 13 02:45:09 floridaseating qmail: 1331621109.213098 starting delivery 1217: msg 33459587 to remote *@sitconf.com
...
Mar 13 02:46:10 floridaseating qmail: 1331621170.273121 delivery 1217: deferral: Sorry,_I_wasn't_able_to_establish_an_SMTP_connection._(#4.4.1)/
```

show us *banal troubles of connectivity*

## Cheap solution

Find SMTP-server, from which both sides are SMTP-reacheable and build backup-MX for domains on it. Deferred on delivery to primary MX will be dropped to backup-MX and later from it - on primary

Comment: how's suite22.ca looking? the only other domain we have an issue with, so far...

Comment: @vulgarbulgar - same hoster as for sitconf, same shit in PTR (*.beanfield.net.) for emitter/collector suite22.ca

Comment: i'm trying to educate myself on how to correct this. i ran a PTR test (http://www.myiptest.com/staticpages/index.php/Reverse-DNS-Lookup) and seem to get a positive result, though i'm not sure how conclusive that is: http://i.imgur.com/7iIpH.png...

Comment: @vulgarbulgar - two ways: a) change IN PTR in reverse-zone to names from forward-zones b) change MX names in forward zones to *.beanfield.net hosts. Anyway, it does not solve (must not) timeout troubles

Comment: how can i investigate timeout troubles? thanks for the assistance thus far.

Comment: telnet host.name 25 and SMTP-session by hand. Ping by long set of ping and counting packet-loss (dirty, not repeatable)

Comment: not sure if i made it clear anywhere, but i only administer floridaseating, and not sitconf.com or suite22.ca - the timeout issues still apply? and not sure how or what timeout issues you are referring to. apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: Udelivered mail is problem of both sides postmasters. When I say about timeout, I say about "deferral: Sorry,_I_wasn't_able_to_establish_an_SMTP_connection" from log

Answer (score 0):

I would find it strange for a setup to block the SMTP handshake/connection based on reverse dns.

Can you please clarify some information?

Your bounceback email states the mail was attempting to be sent TO floridaseating.com FROM sitconf.com and failed.
Yet your image of the queue shows mail being sent FROM floridaseating.com TO sitconf.com.
Also your qmail maillog shows you as floridaseating.com

Do you manage both parties? It's rare for the problem to be seen both ways without one side having more issues than just email to or from one domain. Can you verify the direction the problem is happening in (even tho you mentioned once it was happening both ways).

**THIS->** Based on what I can see it appears sitconf.com might not be setup correctly. It is currently stating the MX server resolves from sitconf.com's host record: 206.223.161.50 though this shows host.interavenuehosting.com as the reverse DNS.
In my first test it reported that it didnt like the RCPT claudio@sitconf.com
In the more recent test it stated there was a local problem
Also one host got blocked because of reaching its limits.

I'd focus my efforts on that server and why it's throwing errors.

Comment: i represent floridaseating.com, and only manage (learning to) that server. the problem consistently exists both ways, when sending and receiving from sitconf.com or suite22.ca.

Comment: "I would find it strange for a setup to block the SMTP handshake/connection based on reverse dns" - I think, they are unrelated issues. I *assumed* RDNS-rejects before reading logs, now 1-st class trouble is poor connectivity